# Twitter Accounts | Single topic, or multiple topics in one account?

Tags: social-network, twitter

Lets assume that I begin a twitter account referencing:

- My preferences towards `MUSIC`
- Inspirational `ART & PHOTOGRAPHY`
- `SHORT STORIES` that I read and enjoy

In my mind, the goal of this account is not only to document my interests, but to also promote the bands, artists, photographers and authors who are `@mentioned`.

Now lets assume that within 6 months, I begin to create my own Art, Photography, Literature and Music. It seems to me that creating a new Twitter about this ( my work process, rough workings, finished projects, alternative edits, etc ) would be a great thing to do.

But, even though each of these accounts have their own content and goals, I feel there is a good reason for combining the content into one project. Bearing in mind that my preferences in music, literature and art - Documented on Account A - is the inspiration for my own work and creations - Documented on Account B.

On the other hand, as one is primarily focused on interests, and the other is a project, I'm not sure if in practice they would go together as well as it looks in theory.

Alternatively, does this scenario work better the other way around - Turning a project based account into one that documents the inspiration behind your work.

Thoughts please?

Comment: Are you trying to promote/build a community of fans/customers?

Comment: Well, to be honest at the moment it's just about publishing some details about great music and creative arts, with the intention to promote the creators ( I used to own a music news website ) in a more personal / chatty sort of way. As for my own work, I obviously want to promote it, but wonder if pushing out too much personal posts would damage the following, or make it more receptive.

Answer (score 1):

Practically this same [question](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/q/3156/3813) was asked (but in reverse) a few days ago.

Quoting from [myself](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/a/3157/3813) therein:

> Usernames are free. As in "don't cost nothin'".
>
> Who cares if one "person" has 1 username, or 100?

If you want to take the time and effort to create & manage more than one account, by all means: do it!

If you *don't*, then don't :)

I've got a few Twitter accounts - but all but one rarely get any love from me, because I just don't have the time to do it